# ./bump-version.sh no such file

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control, terminal

I am getting ready to release for the first time so I do

```
git checkout -b release-1.0 develop
./bump-version.sh 1.0
```

I get back the error:

```
bash: ./bump-version.sh: No such file or directory
```

This is git question. What is the answer in that context?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are following [this guide](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), describing the model commonly known as Git Flow.

Note in the paragraph immediately following what you've done that `bump-version.sh` is not meant to be executed literally:

> After creating a new branch and switching to it, we bump the version number. Here, `bump-version.sh` is a fictional shell script that changes some files in the working copy to reflect the new version. (This can of course be a manual change—the point being that *some* files change.) Then, the bumped version number is committed.

So do whatever makes sense to increment the version number for your project.